# Struct Constructor Only Called Once Per Object

Tags: c#, object, struct, constructor

Is it possible to have a constructor in a struct that is called only once per object? For example, I want code that behaves similarly to this:

```
struct mystruct { /*...*/ }

//later on
mystruct x = 5; //constructor called once, okay
x = 6; //constructor called twice for this object, exception thrown
mystruct y = 6; //different object, this is okay
mystruct z;
z = 7; //this is also okay since the definition didn't call the constructor
```

Is this possible in C#? If not, is there a way to emulate this behavior?

I've tried keeping a static dictionary of `this`'s and testing if a new `this` exists, but that didn't work. Nor will `ObjectIDGenerator`, when testing `this`'s.

Comment: `mystruct x = 5;` Is that even possible ?

Comment: Similar to this `mystruct z;` calls the default constructor if it exists (once). `mystruct z = 5` calls the `overloaded operator =` (not a constructor) which should be implemented by you.

Comment: What are you talking about? The constructor is only ever called once for any specific instance of an object; without a good [mcve] it's impossible to understand what the code you show even does, but assuming you've got an implicit conversion that allows you to assign an `int` literal to a variable of type `mystruct`, the constructor gets called each time you create a new value of the type. What is it you are actually trying to achieve here?

Comment: You seem to be confusing "object" with "variable". The "object" is the value you instantiate via the constructor; by definition, you always construct the object exactly once. The "variable" is the place the object is stored, i.e. `x`, `y`, or `z`. A variable inherently may be assigned arbitrarily many times, and doing so has no effect on the object assigned to it, or the object previously assigned to it. Even if you could do what you seem to be asking, what do you expect to happen if e.g. someone writes `y = x;` after assigning `6` to `y`?

Comment: Okay I reread my code and I'd confused a few aspects of it. I'll try a few more solutions based on what I have.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. What you are asking for is a static constructor. Which by nature has to be parameterless. Which struct contructors can't be.

msdn https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288208(v=vs.71).aspx